# Receiving broadcasts in subclasses of View

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I'm working on designing a subclass of `Button`, which is expected to update every now and then (specifically, whenever particular `Broadcasts` are received). If I were working within the context of an `Activity`, I'd attach the broadcast receivers in `onResume`, and detach them in `onPause`. However, views don't receive these events, and if I attach a listener/receiver, I'm not sure whether I will be able to update the UI if the containing activity is in a "Pause"d state - as well, I'd like to not keep listeners attached when they're not necessary.

So my question is, in a derived View, which is the best way to monitor for external events (via listeners or broadcasts)?

Answer (score 2):

I'm doing something similar where I have subclassed a `TextView`.  I have it structured such that all of my data is received in the Activity, processed, and then sent out to the `TextView`.

The structure I use to send the data is similar to the `Observable/Observer pattern`.  I have an `update()` method in my `TextView` to call which then updates the text.  I have a `List` of `TextViews` that I iterate and call `update()` for each when data is received.  To differentiate between `TextViews` I have a static ID variable assigned upon instantiation.

I think that something similar could be done in your case.  Mine is receiving JSON data over a `Socket` so it should work for a broadcast.